# sprintf into char* var[1] fails with Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, linux

consider code:

```
using std::cout; using std::cerr;
using std::endl; using std::string;
using std::vector;

// . . .

    char* envp[10];

    vector<string> lines;
    char* c_line = nullptr;
    size_t len = 0;

    while ((getline(&c_line, &len, input_file)) != -1) {
        string line;
        lines.push_back(line.assign(c_line));
    }

    fclose(input_file);
    free(c_line);

    sprintf(envp[0], "SERVER=%s", lines[0].data());

    // printing envp[0] here OK

    sprintf(envp[1], "DOMAIN=%s", lines[1].data());

    // printing envp[1] never happened - Segmentation fault prints in output instead
```

I am C# dev I havent used C for couple decades. Something obvious is missing. Mem allocation?

*P.S. I am mixing "old" char * for strings with std strings as the app uses 3rd party dll with chars**

**EDIT** declaring `char envp[10][512];` fails down the line when I try to assing to the 3rd party property `somedllObj.envps = envp;` with `cannot convert char[10][512] to char**`

Comment: you haven't initialised the elements of `envp`

Comment: You need to allocate memory for your pointers with `new`. Example: `char* c_line = nullptr;` -> `char* c_line = new char[100];` Or just `char c_line[100];`

Comment: I do not see where you allocate memory for the `envp` strings before `printf`ing to...

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - i copy pasted that from google. this bit works. perhaps you are right and it is sloppy but its not the problem currently. thanks for your time anyway

Comment: @JohnnyMopp No, if nullpointer, [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) will do so.

Comment: @Aconcagua - how do I allocate for envp properly?

Comment: Ok. Wrong `getline`. But my comment holds true for the pointers in `envp`.

Comment: What do you have to do with `envp`? Can you change the type to `std::vector<std::string>>`?

Comment: I cant - because I have to pass it as char* [] to 3rd party dll

Comment: I do *not* recommend that wild mixture of `std::string` and C-strings. Read everything into `std::string`s directly – all you have then is a `std::vector<std::string>` containing all your data. Then calling into the 3rd party library, create the `char* array[]`, but assign to it the contents of the strings in the vector – `std::string::c_str`! Then pass this array to the library – I assume the library won't store these pointers. If it would, then keep the vector alive as long as the library still needs those strings.

Comment: You can declare `char envp[10][256] ;` for example: 256 chars should be enough for environment variables... But using real C++ instead of old C kind of code should be better anyway.

Comment: @Wisblade: 260 is MAX_PATH, not 256. The drive, colon and backslash as well as trainling \0 need to fit

Comment: You don't necessarily have to store stuff in char arrays to pass it on (read-only) to C-style functions. `std::string` has a [c_str()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member that returns a `const char*`, if that works.

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand - you may be making this task far more difficult than it needs to be by mixing C and C++ code.  This code is almost entirely C, using concepts that are not recommended for any C++ code, with the exception of a `vector` that I assume is really `std::vector`.  You also describe it as C code while tagging it C++.  When this code isn't working, you will need to speak with people experienced in both C and C++ (see earlier comment that assumed the C++ `std::getline` while you were using the C `getline`)

Comment: What does the dll do with the strings pointed to by the pointers in `envp`? Does it just read them or does it modify them?

Comment: @ThomasWeller on some windows versions but the question is tagged linux, even if it was windows new code should assume path can go to [quite a bit further](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd) and linux has a maximum *path* length of 4096 and filename length of 255

Comment: @ThomasWeller It's on Linux, so it's 16384 if I remember well - so it's a big buffer - and the two examples OP gave are just some basic variable assignments (his first `sprintf` even worked...). Correct solution should be to use `std::string` and proper formatting through `std::stringstream`, OR at least to use `snprintf` and `malloc`, but it may be overkill for such a simple problem.

Comment: ok I thought there is 1 line solution for this. I didnt expect so much confusion.. I will try to use @Wisblade advice and format std::string instead.

Comment: @Mgetz: yes, NTFS supports long file names as well since Windows 10 1607 (at least 5 years now) and is configurable via Registry [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recommend mixing `std::string` and old C-strings in such a wild manner. Instead I'd rely on C++ classes as long as possible:

```
std::ifstream inputFile("path to file");
if(!inputFile)
{
    // error handling
}

std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string tmp;
while(std::getline(inputFile, tmp))
{
    lines.emplace_back(std::move(tmp)); // since C++11, not copying the strings...
}

if(!inputFile.eof())
{
    // not the entire file read
    // -> error handling!
}

// TODO: size check; what, if not sufficient lines in file?

lines[0] = std::string("SERVER=") + lines[0];
lines[1] = std::string("DOMAIN=") + lines[1];

std::vector<char*> envp;
envp.reserve(lines.size());
for(auto& l : lines) // C++11: range based for loop...
{
    // note that this ABSOLUTELY requires the library not
    // modifying the strings, otherwise undefined behaviour!
    envp.emplace_back(const_cast<char*>(l.c_str()));

    // UPDATE: this works as well:
    envp.emplace_back(l.data());
    // the string is allowed to be modified, too – apart from
    // the terminating null character (undefined behaviour!)
}

// so far, pure C++...
// now we just get the pointers out of the vector:

libraryFunction(envp.size(), envp.data());
```

Bonus: No manual memory management at all...

(Note: Assuming the strings are **not** modified in the library!)

Comment: I have to pass variable to the library like this: `somedllObj.envps = envp;` where `envps` are `char **`

Comment: this works `envp.emplace_back(l.data());` the proposed l.c_str doesnt - compile time error

Comment: @BoppityBop My fault, `const_cast` missing...

Comment: what kind of tea is that! :)

Comment: @Aconcagua `lines[0] = std::string("SERVER=%s") + lines[0];` should be `lines[0] = std::string("SERVER=") + lines[0];` or `lines[0].insert(0, "SERVER=");`, and the same for `lines[1]`.

Comment: @BoppityBop "*I have to pass variable to the library like this: `somedllObj.envps = envp;`*" - you can use `somedllObj.envps = envp.data();` for that. The `data()` pointer of a `std::vector<char*>` is a `char**` pointer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Copy-paste-error... Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming servers and domains are in the input file, they do not have whitespaces, thus getline is not necessary.

```
vector<string> lines;
std::ifstream input_file("path to file");
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(input_file),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(lines));
lines[0] = "SERVER="s + lines[0];
lines[1] = "DOMAIN="s + lines[1];

std::vector<char*> envp;
for(auto& line : lines)
    envp.emplace_back(line.data());
envp.emplace_back(nullptr);  // Usually env arrays end with nullptr, thus +1 to array size
somedllObj.envps = envp.data();
```